# How would I shorten a memory address so it works in a IntPtr?

Tags: c#, memory, byte, intptr

I'm having a problem. So I'm working on an app that will be able to change a float in memory but the address I'm having is too long for IntPtr.

This is the code I have:

```
VAMemory vam = new VAMemory("APP NAME");

IntPtr ad = 0x264A373E7C0;

vam.WriteByte(ad, (Byte)100);
```

So in this ^ WriteByte it says the IntPtr address is too long. 
I have used this code before and it has worked but somehow it's not working with this address.

Comment: I think you would have to set your project to 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `IntPtr.Size == 4` then your program is targeting *32bit*.

Even if you have selected `AnyCPU` architecture, since VS2013, there is a project build property called `Prefer 32-bit` and it must be turn off on *64bit* machines to get `IntPtr.Size == 8`.

When using the `Perfer 32-Bit` flavor of `AnyCPU`, the semantics are as follows:

- If the process runs on a *32bit* Windows system, it runs as a *32bit* process. *IL* is compiled to *x86* machine code.
- If the process runs on a *64bit* Windows system, it runs as a *32bit* process. *IL* is compiled to *x86* machine code.
- If the process runs on an *ARM* Windows system, it runs as a *32bit* process. *IL* is compiled to *ARM* machine code.